# Android application to store and access data on/from a local server

Tags: android, mysql

There is already a portal system which is based on the web, and allows the teachers to enter the attendance data. But it takes extra efforts from teachers to write it once on paper and then to update the data on the server.

I am **developing an Android application**. This app facilitates the teachers to take attendance of students on mobile itself, then upload it to the server, hence reducing the use of pen and paper. Firstly it asks the user to sign in, then it displays the options of various semesters + sections + subjects which are **fetched from the central server**.

Now, **I know how to make the application, I know MySQL.**

I want to know  what kind of structure is required to make such an
app

1. How do I connect my app to the local server ?
2. Is it necessary to use some web based data storage ?

Answer (score 1):

Because I have not enough repotation to comment. I would advice you to use the [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) libary. It makes rest communication easier. You can include it with gradle and it has many tutorials available.

Answer (score 0):

1. you will have to use [sqLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for local data base in android. you can refer [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) for examples
2. It is not required to use web based data storage as long as you are fine with data being in device itself.

Comment: Data is going to be stored in the server. I do not need it on the device.

Comment: then you need to create web services to sync data between your server and your client.

Comment: Yes, that is what I intend to use. Do you have any idea on how to do all that ?

Comment: you can find many good tutorials on internet on creation and consumption of web services.

Comment: For server , personal opinion here, you could easy use node.js. It even allows you to store the date in json on mongo db so you have one data format accross your backend. Also you should see which data belong to a chat (friendlist, conversations, etc.) and start creating routes for it. Then use RetroFit for communication your backend.